# How I can select data that is above the third quartile in a R-DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, quantile

I would like to select cases with values in some variables above the corresponding third quartile (3)

As my dataset is very large I am going to take as an example the 'Air Quality' database that comes in R.

```
df <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]
```

The objective was to filter by certain columns
('Ozone', 'Solar.R', 'Wind', 'Temp').

Currently I was able to develop this solution:

```
filtro_Ozone = df$Ozone>quantile(df$Ozone)[4]
filtro_Solar.R = df$Solar.R>quantile(df$Solar.R)[4]
filtro_Wind = df$Wind>quantile(df$Wind)[4]
filtro_Temp = df$Temp>quantile(df$Temp)[4]

df[filtro_Ozone & filtro_Solar.R & filtro_Wind & filtro_Temp,]
```

With which I obtain:

```
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
40    71     291 13.8   90     6   9
```

Another fancier way to get this?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: per OP's updated request, you can use filter_at from dplyr to only filter at selected variables:

```
df <- airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]
filter_at(df, vars(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, Temp), ~. > quantile(., probs = 0.75))
```

Comment: I think he might want rows where that's true for every column across the row.

Comment: I put an example of what I want to achieve, your solution seems more suitable, how would you do it to filter by some columns, as shown in the example?

Comment: @JuanJoséTriviño I updated my example with filter_at